# Calling multiple action in redux reset the previous action state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i'm calling these two actions in one action like this

```
import { authenticate } from "./actions/Auth";
import { updateUser } from "./actions/User";

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("logged in");
        this.props.history.push("/");
        this.props.updateAuthState(true, user);
      } else {
        console.log("not logged in");
        this.props.history.push("/signup");
        this.props.updateAuthState(false, {});
      }
    });
  }
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateAuthState: (auth, user) => {
    dispatch(authenticate(auth));
    dispatch(updateUser(user));
  },
});

export default withRouter(connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

auth.js

```
export const authenticate = (isLoggedIn) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "IS_LOGGED_IN",
      payload: isLoggedIn,
    });
  };
};
```

user.js

```
export const updateUser = (user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "UPDATE_USER",
      payload: user,
    });
  };
};
```

first the authenticate update the state of auth to true but after when updateUser is called it sets the auth state to false

image : https://gyazo.com/f4c9b5489020418252e1572c6ddcfa2b

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think they will be called simultaneously rather than one after the other.  So they need to be independent actions that effect different parts of the state and won't override changes made by the other.  In other words, the problem lies in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not dispatch multiple action creators in mapDispatchToProps, it is not stadard way.

Instead use redux-thunk middleware (if you did not do it yet) and create new action creator, which dispatches those two action creators.

Look athis simple example how to integrate and use redux-thunk in your application:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/redux-thunk-explained-with-examples/

When you integrated it, then your could do it this way:

new action creator (e.g. in your auth.js)

```js
export const updateAuthState = (auth, user) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(authenticate(auth)); // you can use promises or asyn/await to achieve some wanted order of dispatches
    dispatch(updateUser(user));
  };
};
```

Changed mapDispatchToProps implementation to this.

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  updateAuthState: (auth, user) => dispatch(updateAuthState(auth, user));
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help i found another solution to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help i have found a solution i needed to merge the previous state with new value in reducer don't know if this is standard but this worked please correct if im wrong

```
let auth = false;
export const isLoggedIn = (state = auth, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "IS_LOGGED_IN":
      return { ...state, auth: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```